# Combine elements of each level of a list using pre-specified function in R

Tags: r

I am working in R and have a list, we'll say named `x`. This list is multidimensional, it contains 100 different outputs of the `survival::survConcordance()` function (i.e. so `x[[i]][j]` where `i` is the number of different `survConcordance()` ouputs (i = 1 to 100) and `j` is the number of elements in each output (j = 1 to 5). What I want to do is for each `i`, compute my concordance statistic, which is a function of the output of `survConcordance()` according to this formula: (for each `i`) `concordance <- (x[[i]][1]+(x[[i]][3] / 2))/(x[[i]][1]+x[[i]][2]+x[[i]][3])`. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. Although I'm virtually certain the solution lies somewhere within the `lapply()` family of functions. Any ideas?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to know if this works without a reproducible example, but from your description of the problem, this should work:

```r
all_concordances <- sapply(x, function(vec) (vec[1] + (vec[3]/2))/ sum(vec[1:3]))
```

This will give you a vector of 100 concordances.

Comment: This is how I first tried to do it, although it didn't work.. however, upon trying again it now works haha. So, thanks! I've got it now!

Comment: Quick follow up question.. would you be able to explain the difference between ```sapply()``` and ```lapply()```? I used the latter instead of the former, as you noted in your answer, but it still worked.

Comment: @jclifto8 sapply just simplifies the return of lapply, making it into a vector instead of a list. Please remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem so other users can see it has a solution. Thanks!